# ObjectInputStream readObject unexpectedly closing socket

Tags: sockets, kotlin, network-programming, serversocket

I want to set up a Server/Client where the client sends a serializable object over a socket to the server. For some reason, I keep getting `java.net.SocketException: SocketClosed` when I try to read the object sent to the server.

Here is my code for the client:

```
class Client(address: String, port: Int) {
    private val connection: Socket = Socket(address, port)
    private var connected: Boolean = true
    private val writer = ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream())
    private val reader = ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream())

    init {
        println("Connected to server at $address on port $port")
    }

    fun run() {
        var sent = false
        while (connected) {
            try {
                if (!sent) {
                    sent = true
                    writer.use {
                        it.writeObject("Hello")
                        it.flush()
                    }
                    println("Sent")
                } else {
                    println("Didn't send")
                }
                Thread.sleep(1000)
            } catch (ex: Exception) {
                ex.printStackTrace()
                shutdown()
            }
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

and here is the code for the server:

```
class ClientHandler(private val client: Socket) {
    private val reader = ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream())
    private val writer = ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream())
    private var running: Boolean = false

    fun run() {
        running = true

        while (running) {
            try {
                reader.use {
                    val packet = it.readObject()

                    when (packet) {
                        is String -> {
                            println("Received packet with data: ${packet}")
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (ex: Exception) {
                ex.printStackTrace()
                shutdown()
            }
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

The output on my server is

```
Server is running on port 9999
Client connected: 127.0.0.1
Received packet with data: Hello
java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:115)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168)
...
```

So, it seems like one instance of my `String` is making it across, but later calls claim that the socket is closed.

Every other post I've seen related to this problem claims that the sender (client) is closing the socket early. However, I know that the client is not closing the socket through its own means. If I change my client code to:

```
class Client(address: String, port: Int) {
    ...
    private val writer = connection.getOutputStream()          // Regular streams
    private val reader = Scanner(connection.getInputStream())

    ...


    fun run() {
        var sent = false
        while (connected) {
            try {
                if (!sent) {
                    sent = true
                    writer.write("Hello\n".toByteArray())    // Send regular byte array
                    println("Sent")
                } else {
                    println("Didn't send")
                }

    ...
}
```

and my server code to:

```
class ClientHandler(private val client: Socket) {
    private val reader = Scanner(client.getInputStream())    // Regular streams
    private val writer = client.getOutputStream()
    private var running: Boolean = false

    fun run() {
        running = true

        while (running) {
            try {
                // Just read lines from stream
                println(reader.nextLine())
            }

    ...
}
```

then my output is what I expect:

```
Server is running on port 9999
Client connected: 127.0.0.1
Hello
```

My only hypothesis is that `.readObject()` is somehow closing the socket connection, forcing the next `readObject()` to throw an exception. This doesn't make too much sense to me, though. Why would that happen?

Answer (score 1):

Digging around through the code for a bit more gave me the answer I needed. It looks like `.use` closes the socket after it finishes. Removing the `use { }` blocks made this work as expected.

Comment: That is because the `use()` method `close()`'s the stream when the specified block of code is complete. This is [documented behavior](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/use.html).